# How to generate a parabolic moving point to form a dynamic graph of parabola?

Tags: animation

1. Enter a standard equation for a parabola
2. According to the input parabolic standard equation, automatically draw the corresponding focal coordinates and guide lines of the parabola in the coordinate system
3. According to the definition of a parabola, the distance from a point on the parabola to the focal point is equal to the distance from the guide line, and the motion trajectory of the point on the parabola is dynamically drawn. The motion trajectory of such a point is the dynamic image of the parabola

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{focus, directrix, equation, parabolaPlot, focusPlot, 
   directrixPlot, movingPointPlot, 
   p = Abs[param]},(*Define the parabola,focus,
  and directrix based on the input form*)
  Switch[form, 
   "y = 2px", {focus = {0, p}, 
    directrix = Line[{{-10, -p}, {10, -p}}], equation = y == 2  p  x},
    "y = -2px", {focus = {0, -p}, 
    directrix = Line[{{-10, p}, {10, p}}], equation = y == -2  p  x}, 
   "x = 2py", {focus = {p, 0}, 
    directrix = Line[{{-p, -10}, {-p, 10}}], equation = x == 2  p  y},
    "x = -2py", {focus = {-p, 0}, 
    directrix = Line[{{p, -10}, {p, 10}}], 
    equation = x == -2  p  y}];
  (*Plot the parabola*)
  parabolaPlot = 
   Plot[Evaluate[Solve[equation, y]], {x, -10, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}];
  (*Plot the focus*)
  focusPlot = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[focus]}];
  (*Plot the directrix*)
  directrixPlot = Graphics[{Dashed, Green, directrix}];
  (*Animate a point moving along the parabola*)
  movingPointPlot = 
   Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Medium], 
     Point[If[
       form == "y = 2px" || form == "y = -2px", {t, 
        2  p  t}, {2  p  t, t}]]}];
  Show[parabolaPlot, focusPlot, directrixPlot, movingPointPlot, 
   Axes -> True]], {{form, "y = 2px", 
   "Select the form of the parabola:"}, {"y = 2px", "y = -2px", 
   "x = 2py", "x = -2py"}}, {{param, 1, "Parameter p (>0)"}, 0.1, 5, 
  0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t, 0, "Animate Point"}, -10, 10, 
  0.1}]
```

The standard equation form for a parabola is y=2px, y=-2px, x=2py, x=-2py, where p>0. The general equation for a parabola is: y==ax ^ 2+bx+c

Step 1: Entering the Equation

Step 2: Drawing the Parabola, Focus, and Directrix
For each form of the parabola, you can calculate the focus and the equation of the directrix.

Step 3: Dynamic Visualization
You want to dynamically illustrate a point moving on the parabola, showing that at any point, its distance from the focus equals its perpendicular distance to the directrix.

Comment: Please note, the standard equation form for a parabola with axes of symmetry parallel to $(x,y)$ axes is $ y^2=2px, x^2=2py $ where p>0.